# Pass from one buffer to another quicly

Tags: buffers

I would like to pass from one buffer to another as in this [website](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ba79534309330accd776a8d2a0712f7c4037d7f9/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f3330363530322f313037323632332f34346332393261302d313439352d313165332d396365362d6463616461336631633533362e676966). Could anyone have an idea how to do such thing? I fact, to open a new window, I use `vnew`, and to change the buffer I use either `:bn`, `:bp` or `:b <file>`.

Comment: Stop bumping your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a quick shortcut to change buffers, checkout [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), which provides a mapping to change buffers using `[b` and `]b` along with many other similarly handy and intuitive mappings.